# How to get whole tems unreded notifications ( activity + chat, etc)

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'have search inside Microsoft documentation Graph API some method to get any kind of unread notifications from Teams product but I didn't see anything relevant that could I use through a REST API.

IS really possible to get the unreaded notifications?

[This badges numbers is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYztX.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> IS really possible to get the unreaded notifications?

Of course, the answer is yes. Currently, there are not existing Team API for this, you need to do it by yourself, meanwhile submit an feature request in the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). A workaround for you: get the message/activity list first, and store the lastModifiedDateTime in your app cache, then use corresponding API to regular interaction with the server to see if any update is available.

> The feed aggregates important content from the following:
>
> ```
> Teams/channels
> Chats
> Apps such as Files, Planner, and your Teams apps
> ```
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/activity-feed

Answer (score 0):

This is on the roadmap but we don't have and dates to share publicly.